# How to move elements without null values to a new array

Tags: java, arrays, null, move

So what I'm trying to do is delete and element from an array and move all existing elements to a new array without the null element. I've already set the element I wanted to null. But when I try to use this code, it only transfers the first element into the array, none of the other elements are moved over. What am I doing wrong?

Side note: I'm not allowed to use ArrayList.

```
   Object[] temp = new Object[sList.length-1];

   for (int j = 0; j < sList.length; j++){ 
         if (sList[j] != null) {
            temp[j] = sList[j];
         }
      }
```

Comment: You need another index (e.g. `int i = 0`) for your `temp` array, then change `temp[j] = sList[j];` to `temp[i++] = sList[j];`

Answer (score 2):

Don't pre-allocate  your array.  Just move the non null values to the front of the array, maintaining order.

```
Integer[] array = {null,1,2,3,null, 4,5,null, 6};
System.out.println("Before move: " + Arrays.toString(array));
int i = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
    if (array[k] == null) {
        continue;
    }
    array[i++] = array[k];
}
System.out.println("After move: " + Arrays.toString(array));
```

Now `i` has the number of elements without nulls. So use that to create a new array.

```
Integer[] result = Arrays.copyOf(array,i);
System.out.println("New Array: " + Arrays.toString(result));
```

Prints

```
Before move: [null, 1, 2, 3, null, 4, 5, null, 6]
After move: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, null, 6]
New Array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

if you're not permitted to use `Arrays.copy()`  you can do it like this.

```
Integer[] result = new Integer[i];
for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
   result[k] = array[k];
}
```

Note:  I did not include other simpler ways (e.g. streams, sets) since if you can't use `ArrayList`, etc, you probably are not supposed to use other more advanced methods either.

Comment: This modifies the old array.  You can still assign over it by simply doing something like `oldArray = new Integer[size];`  Of course, it will be empty but the name will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List<Object>` to create the target `Array`.

```
List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();

for (int j = 0; j < sList.length; j++){ 
    if (sList[j] != null) {
        result.add(sList[j]);
    }
}
Object[] temp = result.toArray();
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use ArrayList for this project. What can I do just using a [] array?

Comment: That makes things a bit more complex, especially when there are several solutions for a problem. As you can see, a question should bring all the important information with it. I think the solution from @WJS is acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

More general solution would be to count the number of `null` in the source array first:

```java
int nullCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < sList.length; i++) {
    if (null == sList[i]) {
        nullCount++;
    }
}

Object[] temp = new Object[sList.length - nullCount];
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < sList.length; i++) {
    Object obj = sList[i];
    if (null != obj) {
        temp[j++] = obj;
    }
}
```

---

Stream API may be used for this task as well (technically, `ArrayList` is not used here :)):

```java
Object[] temp = Arrays.stream(sList).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(Object[]::new);
```